# Python server and Game Client: Message overload?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, game-maker

I'm writing a game server in Python and a game client in Game Maker with the Faucet Networking plugin (though that shouldn't matter). The client sends an UPDATEXY message to the server each time the player moves, and there is a message chatting thing in the client. With 2 clients connected to the server, it seems that the client gets overloaded with messages (further into the run time, chat messages appear slower and the player lags behind where the actual other player is). I believe this is because the client cannot process the messages at the rate they are flowing in, so I implemented a feature in the client where it would just dump all messages in the receive buffer, and ignore them. This seemed to work, but the player would jerk around violently. Is there any sort of 'clean fix' to this problem, or is it a fundamental thing that I have done wrong since the start?

By the way, the protocol I am using is TCP. Is this a problem with TCP itself or am I just using it wrong? Would switching to UDP help?

Thanks.

EDIT: Code was requested so here you go for the server:

```
def sendmsg(msgtype, msg, conn, args=None):
    if msgtype == MSG_PLAYER_ASSIGN_ID:
        dataload = struct.pack('!hhh', MSG_STARTBYTE, msgtype, msg)
        conn.send(dataload)

    elif msgtype == MSG_PLAYER_UPDATEXY: #This will only ever be broadcasted
        #print("Sending xy from " + str(args['pid']))
        dataload = struct.pack('!hhhhh', MSG_STARTBYTE, msgtype, args['pid'], msg[0], msg[1])
        conn.send(dataload)

    elif msgtype == MSG_ASKFORLIST:
        players = msg
        for player in players:
            if args['pid'] != player.pid and player.dead == False:
                dataload = struct.pack('!hhhh' + str(len(str(player.name))) + "s", MSG_STARTBYTE, MSG_PLAYERENTRY, player.pid, len(str(player.name)), player.name.encode())
                conn.send(dataload)
                loginfo("Sent a player")
```

^That's just a few packets, there are more, but they are all pretty much like those

Here you go for the client:

```
if msgtype == MSG_PLAYER_UPDATEXY
{
if tcp_receive(serversocket, 6){
pidtoupdate = read_short(serversocket)
//show_message(string(pidtoupdate))
if objNewNetProcessor.pid != pidtoupdate
{
xtoupdate = read_short(serversocket)
ytoupdate = read_short(serversocket)
playertoupdate = ds_map_find_value(global.players, string(pidtoupdate))
if playertoupdate != objChar
{
playertoupdate.y = ytoupdate
playertoupdate.x = xtoupdate}
}}}

if msgtype == MSG_CHAT
{
if tcp_receive(serversocket, 4){
fromperson = read_short(objNewNetProcessor.serversocket)
strlen = read_short(objNewNetProcessor.serversocket)
tcp_receive(objNewNetProcessor.serversocket, strlen)
chatmsg = read_string(objNewNetProcessor.serversocket, strlen)
display_chat(fromperson, chatmsg)
}}
```

^Sorry that's a total messtastic, it's just temporary code for now. It too is just a few packets, it handles more below that code, though they all look similar to those.

Comment: 1) Kind of hard to debug without any code, 2) seems more related to the handling of messages not the transmission, 3) not really related to python as it's client side most likely.

Comment: @BluePeppers 

1) I figured this was more of a theory question rather than a problem with my code, but if you insist, I'll post it here in a second.

2) I suppose

3) I was wondering if the speed of Python had anything to do with this.

Comment: Is the server replying to every UPDATEXY? Do you know the rate at which these messages are being sent? And how long is it before the client starts to slow down?

Comment: The server relays the UPDATEXY to every client connected. The client runs at a framerate of 60fps and sends the UPDATEXY each time the player moves a pixel. I've never tracked when the player starts to lag behind, but when all the players stand still, it goes back to normal speed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this should work fine, and I doubt this is a problem with high CPU load - 60 updates per second is quite a lot, but with only two clients connected there should not be that much traffic to process. For comparison, Gang Garrison 2 uses only 30 updates per second, but with a decent PC it can handle 20 players on a server just fine. Check the client and server CPU load in task manager to be on the safe side, but I don't expect that to be the problem.

If clearing the "backlog" on the clients makes them catch up, this is probably not a problem with the network speed or the server either, but it might still be valuable to log the traffic on a client with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see if everything looks as expected (e.g. packets are sent and received at the expected rates and are evenly timed).

Since there seems to be a backlog building up on the clients: Do the clients try to consume as many messages as possible each step, or only the messages for one server step? If you only process one server step per client step, any connection hiccups that inevitably happen will cause you to permanently lag behind, which seems to be consistent with what you describe.

Russell Borogove gave you a good pointer as well, definitely make sure that Nagle's algorithm is disabled (=tcp_nodelay is enabled) on each game-related socket on the server. Faucet does this by default.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I let that one slip by! I AM only processing one message per step!

Answer (score 1):

TCP is normally configured to wait up to about 200ms before sending anything if a good-sized chunk of data is not yet ready to be sent (on the order of 100 to 1000 bytes). This is called the Nagle algorithm. With clients trying to send updates at 60fps (~16ms period), this means you'll be bursting a lot of obsolete data.

It is possible to turn off Nagle buffering, but UDP is more appropriate for things like constant position updates in a real-time game.

That said, I would expect a Python server on a reasonably fast machine to be able to keep up with 2 clients' worth of updates, so there may be something else going on.

Comment: Yes, python should be able to do this fine, though I would concider looking into a solution like gevent to run many small tasklets concurrently.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you turn the client update rate down to, say, 10 per second (100ms period), or does it still occur eventually?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. I did try once though, clearing the recvbuffer every 5 seconds, it worked but made the client jerk from the outdated position to the new one.

Comment: Clearing the receive buffer sounds very dangerous - what if the buffer had a fractional message in it at the time? (Or is Faucet handling message boundaries for you at a lower level?)